# put batch file command into VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

Here is batch file code:

```
@echo off >summary.txt (
    for %%F in (*chkpackage.log) do findstr /l %1 "%%F" nul||echo %%  F:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A)
```

and here is the code in VBA Excel calling the batch file:

```
FileSet = Sheet1.Range("C13")
txtFpath = Sheet1.Range("C7").Value
FilePath = txtFpath & "\res.bat"

ChDrive "D"
RSP = Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC"), vbNormalFocus)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "CD " & txtFpath & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "start " & FilePath & " " & FileSet & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "exit " & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "exit " & "{ENTER}", True
```

But I don't want to use a batch file. I want to change it into command to use on VBA.
So i can use only VBA and run command line instead of using VBA to call batch and command line.

Easy explanation is I want to put that command in batch file into Excel-VBA and run it by using VBA call `cmd` and auto input that command to `cmd` like that `Sendkeys` code.

Comment: i have try but it's alway seem to be something wrong in my syntax

i'm about to try your solution :) But I'm not good with programing so i have to take sometime thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (**Tools -> References** from the VBA IDE), which provides the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=VS.84%29.aspx) and allows you to do the following:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fle As Variant
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder(txtFpath).Files
    'processing here
Next
```

You can limit the files to a particular pattern using the [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator:

```
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder(txtFpath).Files
    If fle.Name Like "*chkpackage.log" Then
        'processing here
    End If
Next
```

You can use the [OpenAsTextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method to get a TextStream object, and the **ReadAll** method to read the file contents:

```
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder(txtFpath).Files
    If fle.Name Like "*chkpackage.log" Then
        Dim txt As TextStream, contents As String
        Set txt = fle.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
        contents = txt.ReadAll
        txt.Close

        'process contents of file here
    End If
Next
```

You can use `Split(contents, vbCrLf)` to split the contents into an array of lines before parsing (use `vbLf` or `vbCr` if the line delimiter is Unix/Mac and not Windows).

Alternatively, you can use the `ReadLine` method to read the file line by line. You need to check the `AtEndOfStream` property to ensure that you're not trying to read past the end of the file:

```
'Within the For Each loop
Dim txt As TextStream, currentLine As String
Set txt = fle.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
Do While Not txt.AtEndOfStream
    currentLine = txt.ReadLine

    'process current line here
Loop
txt.Close
```