# how do i get this VBA to run this script without using batch file ( CMD + VBA )

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

i want to know how to run this small line of code without using batch file on Excel VBA

```
  @echo off >summary.txt (
  for %%F in (*chkpackage*) do findstr /l %1 "%%F" nul||echo %%F:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A
)
```

i just want to use only vba or only run cmd line to run this line of code

thx you :)

Comment: http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/822451-solved-vba-macro-opens-command.html would this be helpful?

Comment: Do you mean you specifically want to use VBA to run this line from the command-line? If not, you've asked the same question already. If the answer there is not acceptable, please modify your original question, or add comments to clarify.

Comment: Do you want to run the equivalent of this line of code, but in VBA? So same result, but different language?

Comment: yep i got it now  thank you 

Zev spitz  

thank you a lot 

:D

Comment: possible duplicate of [put batch file command into VBA Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814994/put-batch-file-command-into-vba-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Change this line from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814994/put-batch-file-command-into-vba-excel):

```
If fle.Name Like "*chkpackage.log" Then
```

To:

```
If fle.Name Like "*chkpackage*" Then
```

Comment: i'm sorry i quite dont understand your past answer becuase of my skill level i need more simple thing than that but i really thank you a lot i need to practice more then i can understand it sincerely thank you